# Android native and InfoWindow method

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm writing a map-based app on Android using Maps API v2.

I already have markers being placed on the map, and can display custom info windows for those markers, but AFAICT only one info window can be displayed at a time. There are a couple of spots where I want different behaviour: I want to always display the info window for multiple windows, without a marker showing.

This is my code:

```
package teamtreehouse.com.iamhere;

import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    /*
     * Define a request code to send to Google Play services
     * This code is returned in Activity.onActivityResult
     */
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        // Create the LocationRequest object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
     * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
     * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
     * <p/>
     * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
     * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
     * <p/>
     * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
     * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
     * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
     * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
     * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
     */
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }






    }



    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
     * just add a marker near Africa.
     * <p/>
     * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
     */
    private void setUpMap() {
        List<Marker> lstMarcadores =  new ArrayList<>();

        Marker marker;
        marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng( -27.585490, -66.305299))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.airport))
                .title("Restaurante")
        .snippet("Gato"));
        lstMarcadores.add(marker);
        lstMarcadores.get(0).showInfoWindow();


        Marker marker2;
        marker2 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng( -26.585456, -66.305299))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.airport))
                .title("EL TORO")
        .snippet("Gato"));
        lstMarcadores.add(marker2);
        lstMarcadores.get(1).showInfoWindow();

//        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
//                .position(new LatLng(-27.581992, -66.314411))
//                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.acupuncture))
//                .title("Hotel"));

       /* GoogleMap mMapf = null;
        mMapf.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(-27.583069, -66.313380))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.airport))
                .title("OSDE"));

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng( -27.581094, -66.313418))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.airport))
                .title("Otro Hotel"));

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng( -27.585490, -66.305299))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.airport))
                .title("Restaurante Viejo Lobo"));
*/




            }











    private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());

        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)).title("Localizacion Actual"));
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.airport))
                .title("Hola! Usted se encuentra en este punto.");
        mMap.addMarker(options);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (location == null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
        else {
            handleNewLocation(location);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        /*
         * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
         * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
         * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
         * error.
         */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                /*
                 * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
                 * PendingIntent
                 */
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            /*
             * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
             * user with the error.
             */
            Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }
}
```

And this is my xml. I use this file to get images, tittles and descriptions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="148dp"
            android:layout_height="148dp"
            android:id="@+id/hotel_uno"
            android:src="@drawable/hotel"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="192dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Hotel Aquasol"
                android:id="@+id/textView"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Cuatro estrellas"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="147dp"
            android:id="@+id/hotel2"
            android:src="@drawable/hoteldos"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Onion"
                android:id="@+id/onion"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: there is no such thing as maps api v3 on android, you are using v2

Comment: If you are using [Maps Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows), It says here that an `infoWindow` allows you to display information to the user when they tap on a marker. Only one `infowindow` is displayed at a time. If user clicks another marker, the current `infowindow` will be hidden and the new `infowindow` will be displayed. So for my understanding, you want to display multiple `infoWindows` for multiple markers. Then I think you can do it using [Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows).

Comment: JavaScript in Android Native App?